# Ext js how to pair checkbox & textfield?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a fieldset with textfield checkbox pairs, how do i align them in rows so that i have like below, thanks in advance.

```
   [CHECKBOX] [TEXTBOX] 
   [CHECKBOX] [TEXTBOX] 
   [CHECKBOX] [TEXTBOX]
```

Comment: You don't want to use the label for the checkbox?  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`fieldContainer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer) with [`layout: 'hbox'`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox) configuration.

For example:

```
var formConfig = {
    xtype: 'form'
    // Your form configuration here
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: 'My pair label', // If you want a label for both fields, or you can put fieldLabel to either/both/none fields
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'middle', // or any other align of your choosing
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    // your checkbox configuration here, i.e. hideLabel: true or fieldLabel: 'checkbox label'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    // your textfield configuration here
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```